# Why are the tiles not appearing when they should be drawn?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am making a game, I have the basic player movement down and its sprite animation. However the grass tiles I'm trying to paste onto the background, do not appear to be drawn.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

// Variables
var tileSize = 32;
var tilex = Math.ceil(canvas.width / tileSize);
var tiley = Math.ceil(canvas.height / tileSize);
var tiles = [];
var player = [];
var playerState = 'idle';
var keyPresses = {};
var userSize = 128;

// Event Listeners
window.addEventListener('keydown', keyDownListener, false);
function keyDownListener(event) {
  keyPresses[event.key] = true;
};

window.addEventListener('keyup', keyUpListener, false);
function keyUpListener(event) {
  keyPresses[event.key] = false;
  playerState = 'idle';
};

//TileImages grass, stone, and structure
for (let i = 0; i < 156; i++) {
    tiles[i] = new Image();
    tiles[i].src = 'performanceTask Assets/tiles/tile' + i.toString() + '.png';
};

//Player Images idle and movement
for (let i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    player[i] = new Image();
    player[i].src = 'performanceTask Assets/player/player' + i.toString() + '.png';
};

class Map {
    xTileLocation = 0;
    yTileLocation = 0;
    grassLand() {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.tiley; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j< this.tilex; j++) {
                ctx.drawImage(this.tiles[0], this.xTileLocation, this.yTileLocation);
                this.xTileLocation += this.tileSize;
            };
            this.xTileLocation = 0;
            this.yTileLocation += this.tileSize;
        };
        this.xTileLocation = 0;
        this.yTileLocation = 0;
    };
};

class Player {
    x = canvas.width/2;
    y = canvas.height/2;

    tick = 0;
    playerImage = player;
    state = playerState;

    movementSpeed = 5;
    draw() {
        this.state = playerState

        // Movement
        if (keyPresses.w) {
            this.y -= this.movementSpeed;
            playerState = 'moving';
        }
        if (keyPresses.s) {
            this.y += this.movementSpeed;
            playerState = 'moving';
        }
        if (keyPresses.a) {
            this.x -= this.movementSpeed;
            playerState = 'moving';
        }
        if (keyPresses.d) {
            this.x += this.movementSpeed;
            playerState = 'moving';
        }





        // IDLE STATE
        if (this.state == 'idle') {
            if(this.tick==20 || this.tick > 20) {
                this.tick = 0;
            };
            ctx.drawImage(this.playerImage[this.tick], this.x - 64, this.y + 64, 128, 128);
        }
        else {
            if (this.state == 'moving') {
                if(this.tick < 21 || this.tick == 39) {
                    this.tick = 21;
                };
                ctx.drawImage(this.playerImage[this.tick], this.x -64, this.y + 64, 128, 128);
            }
        }
        this.tick = this.tick + 1;
    };
};

let user = new Player();
let map = new Map();
function gameLoop() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    map.grassLand();
    user.draw();
};
setInterval(gameLoop, 1000/24);
```

The code that is not working is located in the `Map` class.

I have tried to read through the javascript documentation, but have found nothing. There are no errors and nothing seems to work. Each tile is 32px by 32px.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the shortest code necessary to replicate the issue.

Comment: Make a copy of your project, reduce it to a basic template, add your code back in bit by bit, and then find the point when it stops working. The code you’ve provided can be simplified considerably, which would make it much easier to fix.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that your `Map.grassland` function refers to `this.tilex` and `this.tiley` that are not defined in that class. If you haven't already, I would recommend you learn to use how to use the debugger to step through your code. Most browsers have built-in developer tool that include a debugger. You can manually add a debugging breakpoint to your code using the `debugger` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You decided to use [Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) -- that is fine, but then try to keep all variables part of the object created (like the tileSize).

There was something about the logic in the grassLand method that was a bit off, so I refactured that part. I hope that you like the map and forEach functions that replaced the for loops.

Be aware that assets (like the images) need to be loaded before you can draw them on the canvas. Maybe you should have some kind of load routine for alle assets before everything else.

```js
// SVG image for testing
var svgimg = "data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTAgMTAiIHdpZHRoPSIzMiIgaGVpZ2h0PSIzMiIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj4KICA8ZGVmcz4KICAgIDxsaW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudCBpZD0iZzEiIGdyYWRpZW50VHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMzIpIj4KICAgICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSI1JSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iZ3JlZW4iIC8+CiAgICAgIDxzdG9wIG9mZnNldD0iOTUlIiBzdG9wLWNvbG9yPSJkYXJrZ3JlZW4iIC8+CiAgICA8L2xpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50PgogIDwvZGVmcz4KPHJlY3Qgd2lkdGg9IjEwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwIiBmaWxsPSJ1cmwoI2cxKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+";
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

class Canvasmap {
  constructor(tileSize) {
    this.tileSize = tileSize;
    this.tilex = Math.ceil(canvas.width / tileSize);
    this.tiley = Math.ceil(canvas.height / tileSize);
    this.createTiles();
  }
  createTiles() {
    //TileImages grass, stone, and structure
    this.tiles = [...Array(this.tilex).keys()].map(x => {
      return [...Array(this.tiley).keys()].map(y => {
        let img = new Image();
        img.src = svgimg;
        /* if you need a numbered img src you can use
        the x and y variable src = `path/img${(x+1) * (y+1)}.png`
        or whatever fits*/
        return img;
      })
    });
  }

  grassLand() {
    this.tiles.forEach((arr, i) => {
      arr.forEach((img, j) => {
        let yTileLocation = this.tileSize * i;
        let xTileLocation = this.tileSize * j;
        ctx.drawImage(img, xTileLocation, yTileLocation, this.tileSize, this.tileSize);
      })
    });
  }
};

let map = new Canvasmap(32);

function gameLoop() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  map.grassLand();
};

setInterval(gameLoop, 1000 / 24);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="320"></canvas>
```